# Netty client would not connect

Tags: netty

Some odd behavior with Netty. I am trying to connect to a backend that talks custom protocol, and was written in Mina 1.1.7 (for what it is worth).

I have code like this:

```
    ChannelFuture cFuture = client.connect(new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 8081));
    cFuture.awaitUninterruptibly(5000);
    if(!cFuture.isSuccess()) {
        return;
    }
```

Connection to the server fails. I tried to telnet to that same location and connection gets established.

I also have the same code that works for Discard example. There server side is also Netty and no problems. Any clue as to

1. What might be wrong?
2. How do I make Netty a bit more verbose, so I at least get a clue as to what might be happening?

Cheers,
Alex.

Answer (score 0):

Can you show us what happens if you call:

```
ChannelFuture cFuture = ....
cfuture.awaitUninterruptibly();
if (!cFuture.isSuccess) {
    cFuture.getCause().printstackTrace();
}
```

This seems like a connection problem here.

Comment: Actually, I tried that and I get NPE. since  there is no cause. I did however manage to get it going. Strangely enough my pipeline was not up-to-snuff. I changed it around a bit and now I am in business. What's odd is that netty does not complain at all. Not nice of Netty to give me a silent treatment :-) Thanks for your tip though.

Comment: if cFuture.isSuccess() is false there must be some cause and so its impossible to get a NPE on printstackTrace()